Notepad++ mode for git commit messages
I want to use Notepad++ to help formatting git commit messages.
NOTE: this is NOT a question about setting up git to open Notepad++ as its editor, I know about git config. This is NOT about running git commands from Notepad++ either. Stating this here because that's what all my search results were about.
I want Notepad++ to recognize that it is editing a file called COMMIT_EDITMSG, and enter a mode that somehow:

warns about title length larger than 72
warns about a non-empty second row
does line breaks at 80 in the detailed description
applies colors for e.g. comments

Here is how I have it in another editor, and what I would like to mimic in Notepad++:

EDIT to make the questions explicit:

is there such a mode for Notepad++?
is this feasible at all in Notepad++?
how would I go about creating one?
are there easy to use and lightweight alternatives to Notepad++ that would provide that functionality?


Seems https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/user-defined-language-system/ might be a starting point.

There's no question here in the 1st place.

@Destroy666 there is now.
